# How shall I approach search result caching for this MVC3 / RavenDB app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, ravendb

In my simple MVC3 application users can perform searches against my data, which is held in a RavenDB database at RavenHQ.  I know that RavenDB caches proactively, but I'd like to avoid the http call to RavenHQ in the first place by caching searches. It's likely that each user will perform the same search more than once, and it's also likely that different users will perform the same searches. The data won't change more often than weekly.

The search params are properties of a search object. I've tried without success using output caching on the action (below), varying on the search object. It may be that I need to vary by each property of the search object individually, but that seems unsatisfactory as I may in the future add more properties.

How would you approach this?

1. Output caching on the action varying by search.AccName, etc.
2. No caching in web app, rely on RavenDB caching.
3. Use HttpRuntime.Cache (but if so, how)?
4. Some other strategy.

Excuse code formatting, had some problems with that.

```
public class AccItemSearch
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string AccName { get; set; }
    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }
} 

public class AccItemSearchResults
{
    public IEnumerable<AccItem> AccItems { get; set; }
    public AccItemSearch Search { get; set; }
}

public PartialViewResult Accommodation(AccItemSearch search)
{
    var accItems = new List<AccItem>();
    using (IDocumentSession session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
    {
        // fill accItems collection by querying the RavenDB database
    }
    return PartialView(new AccItemSearchResults 
    {
        AccItems = accItems.ToList(), Search = search
    });
}
```

Comment: You are returning a partial view in this action, but how is it included on the page? Do you invoke this async with js, or output it using @Html.Action? If the latter, you may want to look into donut hold caching https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+donut+hole+caching . Otherwise, I would start out by applying the OutputCacheAttribute to the action. You can vary it by all params by doing `[OutputCache(VaryByParams = "*")]`

Comment: I'm calling the action async from the client. I did try OutputCache, but found that it always returned the same data.

Comment: So it cached and returned the first call always, even if the 2nd and 3rd calls had different property values in the AccItemSearch instance? Did you have the `VaryByParam` set to `"*"` on the cache attribute?

Comment: That was the conclusion I came to, but I'll try it again in case I'm being a dick. Because it wouldn't be the first time today that's happened :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RavenDB has builtin support for that, see:
http://ayende.com/blog/25601/ravendb-aggressive-caching-mode

Comment: Awesome - I think that's what I was looking for in this case. I had assumed that RavenDB caching would be taking place on the db server rather than the webserver. RavenDB gets better and better the more I look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing this action method asynchronously, I would try using the OutputCache attribute:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 1800)]
public PartialViewResult Accommodation(AccItemSearch search)
{
    var accItems = new List<AccItem>();
    using (IDocumentSession session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
    {
        // fill accItems collection by querying the RavenDB database
    }
    return PartialView(new AccItemSearchResults 
    { 
        AccItems = accItems.ToList(), Search = search 
    });
}
```

The VaryByParam should tell it to cache separately based on the properties in your search viewmodel argument.